# Refresh data in shiny app using shared folder excel sheet

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I've created a shiny app that creates a graph based on data that's entered in daily via a shared excel sheet (.xlsx) that is in a shared folder (an L drive).

How would I format or upload the data so that it is able to be refreshed whenever a new daily line of data is entered?

Answer (score 2):

Here is one possible approach along with reference documentations:

- Create a workflow to fetch the data using its URL:
  [read in online xlsx - sheet in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028408/read-in-online-xlsx-sheet-in-r)
- Make the data retrieval process reactive:
  https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html
- Set a `reactiveTimer` to periodically check for updates:
  https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.0/reactiveTimer.html

By doing so, your app will fetch the document on a regular basis to update your graph. If you want real time updates (i.e. every time there is a change in the document), you have to be able to trigger the application from outside, which is more complicated (especially via Excel).

**Update:**

Following up your comment; you don't need the data to be online. You are fine if you are able to import it into R. Just make this process reactive and set a timer to refresh everyday (see the documentation for examples). Alternatively you can have an `actionButton` to refresh manually.

Comment: Thank you however I do not believe our shared folder is online. It's in a network drive which can be accessed by employees only. Is this still possible?

Comment: Yes, you can. Updated my answer to address your question.