# Scraping with {rvest} yields "character (empty)"?

Tags: css, r, rvest

I've been scraping a file, but now there's a new URL - I just tried to chg. the URL and CSS-selector - but my `link`-object don't result in a searchpath but "character (empty)" - what's seems to be the problem?

Site: https://arbetsformedlingen.se/statistik/statistik-om-varsel

I want to grab the file "Tillfällig statistik per län och bransch, januari-april 2023" in the 'box' *Antal varsel och berörda personer*.

R-code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringr)
library(rio) #import-function
library(rvest) #read_html()-function


# Link to target site
url <- "https://arbetsformedlingen.se/statistik/statistik-om-varsel"

## Parsa HTML-innehållet
doc <- read_html(url)

## Hitta data som du vill skrapa
### Select CSS locator
link <- html_elements(doc, css = '#cardContainer > app-downloads:nth-child(3) > div > div:nth-child(3) > div > digi-link-internal > digi-link > a') %>%
  html_attr("href")

# Create URL for file download
url2 <- "https://arbetsformedlingen.se"
full_link <- sprintf("%s%s", url2, link)

# Get and save file locally
td = tempdir()              # skapa temporär mapp
varsel_fil <- tempfile(tmpdir=td, fileext = ".xlsx")
download.file(full_link, destfile = varsel_fil, mode = "wb")   

# Read file into a df
df_imported <- import(varsel_fil, which=1) #which - välj 'sheet'-nr
```

Previously the css-argument in the `html_elements`-function was `#svid12_142311c317a09e842af1a94 > div.sv-text-portlet-content > p:nth-child(20) > strong > a`

-> So the beginning is quite different - I don't understand what it implies though..

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: The desired table appears to be an Excel file with its own download link now (https://arbetsformedlingen.se/download/18.793fa1821869801540c14b3/1683719045927/web-varsel-bransch-lan-2023.xlsx). For downloading and processing an Excel file from an URL, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028408/read-in-online-xlsx-sheet-in-r

Comment: Yes, but this link get's updated (replaced) with a new .xlsx each month - so I can't use the unique URL because it will change(?) I used the selector to get the latest URL in my code each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That page is now mostly rendered by JavaScript and most of that content is not included in the page source, you can check by disabling JS for the site in your browser. List of files in the described box is pulled from `https://arbetsformedlingen.se/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision`.

A quick way to find this API endpoint would be through the network tab of browser's developer tools -- after launching dev tools, refresh the page to capture all requests and search for some phrase that can't be found from the source of the main page, i.e. "januari-april", looks something [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKEnU.png). Once the API endpoint with file list is identified, we can extract the file URL and proceed with the download:

```r
library(dplyr)
url_ <- "https://arbetsformedlingen.se/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision"
xlsx_response <- jsonlite::fromJSON(url_, simplifyVector = FALSE) %>% 
  # there are 3 files listed, naively picking the last one; 
  # may or may not work in a long run
  dplyr::last() %>% 
  # we could also use purrr::keep() **before** last() to keep only 
  # the record with matching name, like 
  # purrr::keep(~ .x$name == "Länktext till varsel tillfällig statistik")
  purrr::pluck("properties", "link") %>% 
  # combine first part of url_ and extracted link to get full URL for the file
  # last parameter, ".", is where the output of previous pipe ends up 
  # next expression evaluates as:
  # str_replace("https://arbetsformedlingen.se/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision", "(?<=\\w)/.*", "/download/18.793fa1821869801540c14b3/1683719045927/web-varsel-bransch-lan-2023.xlsx")
  stringr::str_replace(url_, "(?<=\\w)/.*", .) %>%
  httr2::request() %>% 
  # we can store the file by setting the path
  httr2::req_perform(path = file.path(tempdir(), basename(.$url)))

# httr2 response:
xlsx_response
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET
#> https://arbetsformedlingen.se/download/18.793fa1821869801540c14b3/1683719045927/web-varsel-bransch-lan-2023.xlsx
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
#> Body: On disk 'body'

# open file location:
# browseURL(xlsx_response$body[1])
```

Downloaded file:

```r
readxl::read_xlsx(xlsx_response$body[1], 1, "A4:Y26") %>% glimpse()
#> New names:
#> • `` -> `...1`
#> • `` -> `...2`
#> • `` -> `...25`
#> Rows: 22
#> Columns: 25
#> $ ...1  <chr> "SNI-kod", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K"…
#> $ ...2  <chr> "Näringsgren", "Jordbruk, skogsbruk och fiske", "Utvinning av mi…
#> $ AB    <chr> "Stockholms län", "5", NA, "56", NA, NA, "256", "384", "141", "3…
#> $ C     <chr> "Uppsala län", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "18", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,…
#> $ D     <chr> "Södermanlands län", NA, NA, NA, NA, "8", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ E     <chr> "Östergötlands län", NA, NA, "20", NA, NA, "61", NA, "17", NA, N…
#> $ F     <chr> "Jönköpings län", NA, "5", "246", NA, NA, NA, "21", NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ G     <chr> "Kronobergs län", NA, NA, "201", NA, NA, "19", NA, NA, NA, NA, N…
#> $ H     <chr> "Kalmar län", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "15", NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ I     <chr> "Gotlands län", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ K     <chr> "Blekinge län", NA, NA, "9", NA, NA, NA, "18", NA, NA, NA, NA, N…
#> $ M     <chr> "Skåne län", NA, NA, "30", NA, NA, "57", "63", NA, NA, "46", NA,…
#> $ N     <chr> "Hallands län", NA, NA, "24", NA, NA, "15", "6", NA, NA, NA, NA,…
#> $ O     <chr> "Västra Götalands län", NA, NA, "62", NA, NA, "120", "27", "96",…
#> $ S     <chr> "Värmlands län", NA, NA, "20", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "10", NA, NA,…
#> $ T     <chr> "Örebro län", NA, NA, "47", NA, NA, NA, "8", NA, "18", NA, NA, "…
#> $ U     <chr> "Västmanlands län", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, …
#> $ W     <chr> "Dalarnas län", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "15", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ X     <chr> "Gävleborgs län", NA, NA, "32", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "50", NA, NA…
#> $ Y     <chr> "Västernorrlands län", NA, NA, "10", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,…
#> $ Z     <chr> "Jämtlands län", NA, NA, "14", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "6", NA, …
#> $ AC    <chr> "Västerbottens län", NA, NA, "50", NA, NA, "9", NA, "16", NA, NA…
#> $ BD    <chr> "Norrbottens län", NA, NA, "6", NA, NA, "15", "6", NA, NA, NA, N…
#> $ `-`   <chr> "Uppgift saknas", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA…
#> $ ...25 <chr> "Riket", "5", "5", "827", NA, "8", "585", "533", "285", "125", "…
```

<sup>Created on 2023-05-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

More base-like approach would perhaps be:

```r
download.file(paste0("https://arbetsformedlingen.se",
                     jsonlite::read_json("https://arbetsformedlingen.se/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision")[[3]]$properties$link),
              file.path(tempdir(),"out.xlsx"), mode = "wb")
```

Comment: Great! I disabled JS in Chrome and you're right, almost nothing is shown except the bottom with news ("Nyheter"). How did you identify that URL though? I'm looking through the HTML-code and can't find it?

Comment: So I've managed to understand the code down to ```stringr::str_replace(url_, "(?<=\\w)/.*", .) ``` - I'm not so used to pipes, I try to avoid them, because I'm not so fluent yet. But I guess we are merging the beggining of the URL and the last path to the file - but what's going on with the citation and the dot last?

Comment: Also I tried modifying the code in the end w what I was familiar w - didn't work, why? Beacuse the final ```xlsx_response```-object is not a URL but some kind of SQL-url or query?

`full_link <- sprintf("%s%s", url_, xlsx_response) #xlsx just the end here

#Get and save
td = tempdir()              # skapa temporär mapp
varsel_fil <- tempfile(tmpdir=td, fileext = ".xlsx")
download.file(full_link, destfile = varsel_fil, mode = "wb")   

#Import data
df <- import(varsel_fil, which=1)`

Comment: For finding out which API endpoinds provide certain content (i.e. where that list of of file is coming from), network tab of browsers dev tools is probably the best first stop (added a note in the answer). Regarding `.`, this is where the output from last pipe ends up, partial xlsx URL in this case.  `xlsx_response` is the result of performed request. I.e it holds the status code of the request and URL that was already requested, also the local path to saved location. Actual downloading happens in `httr2::req_perform()`

Comment: Added a small base-like variant with no pipes and no other dependencies but `jsonlite`

Comment: And that `"(?<=\\w)/.*"` regex in `str_replace` uses positive look-behind to find the first word-char-forward -slash pair (`e/` in this case) to replace everything that comes after `https://arbetsformedlingen.se` with partial xlsx URL. https://regex101.com/r/Fn01EY/1 makes probably better job explaining how it works.

Comment: Thanks, I'm completely green on this.. 1. I opened DevTools (never done before), but I can't find what you see - what browser do you use? 2. Sorry I still do not understand what happens on the stringr-line :S. It use url_ and combine with the end but still the output after that line has nothing with "sitevision" in it?

Comment: So `"(?<=\\w)/.*"` basically convert the URL to the "basic" URL? But if that's the case I don't undertand why we use {httr2}? Sorry I'm so new to API, json and all.. :o

Comment: I'm mostly on Chrome, but all other browsers provide the same set of tools.  You most likely end up in element inspector first and have to switch to network tab. If search in network tab is not visible, ctrl+f should bring it up (at least in Chrome on Windows).

Comment: Regular expression are mighty-powerful for extracting and replacing parts of text, but those are almost always easier to write than explain.  It evaluates as: `str_replace("https://arbetsformedlingen.se/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision", "(?<=\\w)/.*", "/download/18.793fa1821869801540c14b3/1683719045927/web-varsel-bransch-lan-2023.xlsx")`  and yes, it replaces the `/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision` part in first parameter with the 3rd parameter.

Comment: I need to dwnl Chrome on my Mac then, because I don't have those rights on company computer to open DevTools in Chrome, and in IE I don't find anything about "sitevision", I got into "Network", downloaded it, get some records but nothing that I can find there helps me identify the correct URL to give to `read_json`-function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253755/discussion-between-christian-and-margusl).

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to @margusl this code would suffice to do what my original code did:

```
# Create temp dir, download file locally
td = tempdir() ## created temp map
varsel_fil <- tempfile(tmpdir=td, fileext = ".xlsx")

## Download file
download.file(paste0("https://arbetsformedlingen.se",
                     jsonlite::read_json("https://arbetsformedlingen.se/rest/analysportalen/va/sitevision")[[3]]$properties$link),
              destfile = varsel_fil, mode = "wb")


#Importera file as df
df <- import(varsel_fil, which=1) #which - sheet nbr
```

This code select third list from json-response, it's a good idea to first create an object and inspect the json-response. The first suggestion (with more code) is a bit more rigid and select list based on criteria.